# Magento 2.4.0 Installation Error

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.4, magento2.4.0, database-connection

I am getting this error in during installation of Magento 2.4.0 on Live server.

Please help if you can.

**Current version of RDBMS is not supported. Used Version: 5.6.49-cll-lve. Su
pported versions: MySQL-8, MySQL-5.7, MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)**

Please check screenshot.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: did you install elasticsearch and other required php_modules before installation?

Comment: No I have not installed, I am using go daddy, How to I can install these modules ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to go through [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about updating to a newer version of MySQL? As the error literally says, your current RDBMS is not supported, but MySQL 8, 5.7 or MariaDB 10.2 to 10.4 are supported.